# Importing CSV but I only want to base the insert point on the last row in Column A

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an app script that imports CSV files to columns A:E. The problem I have is that if I add any data to say Column H, then my app script starts the import below that data instead of below the last row of data in the actual columns that I am importing into. I need the script to only judge the data in the first 4 columns.
I tried range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow())
Here is the code I am using.

```js
function writeDataToSheet(data) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
    //const range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    const range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow()+1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    return sheet.getName();
  }
```

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | .... | Col H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | DATA |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | DATA |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |
| DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | .... |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of `const range = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow()+1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);`, 5 arguments are used in the method of `getRange`. In this case, 4 arguments are used.
- In your script, it seems that `range` is not used.
- In your situation, how about checking the last row of the column "A"?

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function writeDataToSheet(data) {
  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() + 1 : offsetRow;
  };
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1), 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}
```

- By this modification, the values of `data` is put from the next row of the last row of column "A".

Comment: After looking at your answer and checking my script, it does appear that it isn't being used. But why does it "work" for finding the lastRow() + 1?    I am going to try your answer and will check back. Thank you!

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you for this.

Comment: @Heath Atchley Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.